# Is solving this regular expression error in Dart code and getting my goal done possible?

Tags: regex, dart

I have the following code:

```
void main() {
    String date_string = "2024-03-07";
    var regex = RegExp(r'^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$');
    var matches = regex.firstMatch(date_string);

    String? str_year = "";
    String? str_month= "";
    String? str_day = "";
    int year = 0;
    int month = 0;
    int day = 0;

    if ( matches != null ) {
        str_year = matches.group(1);
        str_month = matches.group(2);
        str_day = matches.group(3);
    }

    regex = RegExp(r'^0+([^0]+)');
    matches = regex.firstMatch(str_year);
    if ( matches != null ) {
        print(matches.group(1));
    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
regex_parse_date.dart:20:32: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
    matches = regex.firstMatch(str_year);
                               ^
```

My purpose is to parse/validate the date and assign them to the integer variables year, month, and day.

UPDATE:

I also tried the following but did not work either:

```
void main() {
    String date_string = "2024-03-07";
    var regex = RegExp(r'^0?([0-9]+)-0?([0-9]+)-0?([0-9]+)$');
    var matches = regex.firstMatch(date_string);

    int year = 0;
    int month = 0;
    int day = 0;

    if ( matches != null ) {
        year = int.parse(matches.group(1));
        month = int.parse(matches.group(2));
        day = int.parse(matches.group(3));
    }

    print(year);
    print(month);
    print(day);
}
```

Comment: @esqew, Sorry, but the link doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: @esqew, I've checked for `not null` condition, but still there are errors.

Comment: Change `String? str_year = "";` to `String str_year = "";`. There's no need for nullability because you never set it to `null`.

Comment: Using a regexp for the second test seems like overkill. Just use `str_year.startsWith("0")`

Comment: @Barmar, I tried and got error `Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.`

Comment: I didn't get the meaning of `str_year.startsWith("0")` ?

Comment: What don't you get? Isn't your second regexp testing whether the first character of `str_year` is `0`?

Comment: Never mind, now I see that it's skipping over all the `0` characters at the beginning, because of `0+`.

Comment: Use `int.tryParse(str_year ?? "")` as shown in the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `regex.firstMatch(String input)` requires that the variable `input` be of type `String` and not `String?`.

Below sample code that extracts the required numbers:

```
void main() {
  String dateString = "2024-03-07";
  var regex = RegExp(r'^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$');
  var matches = regex.firstMatch(dateString);

  int year = 0;
  int month = 0;
  int day = 0;

  if (matches != null) {
    year = int.parse(matches.group(1)!);
    month = int.parse(matches.group(2)!);
    day = int.parse(matches.group(3)!);
  }

  print('$year - $month - $day');
}
```

Comment: Note: Your working code should validate the matches and make sure that they can be parsed to an `int`.

Comment: More validation than the regular expression?

Comment: If `dateString` is guaranteed to always have the same format then it will work as it is. But it does not work for example with: `var dateString = '2024-03- 7'`.